# How to access or add the ArrayList inside of another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble with accessing an ArrayList inside of another ArrayList.
Like so:

```
    public class Bar{
        private static ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();

        public static void main(String[] args){
            prepArrayLists();

            // This is what's not working (the next two lines)
            ArrayList<Foo> temp = fooParent.get(0);
            temp.add(new Foo(23, "Cows", true);
        }

        private static void prepArrayLists(){
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
                fooList.addAll(new ArrayList<Foo>());
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler wouldn't let me do this. What I am trying to do is put an ArrayList of components (Foo) into another ArrayList, where I can sort it for other purposes.

I would like to stick with ArrayList of ArrayLists because I'm trying to see how this works. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You don't currently have an arraylist of arraylist. You have an arraylist of Foo. Try and change your foolist to `private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>> fooList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your program does.

1. You have an `ArrayList` of `Foo` called `fooList`.  It can contain `Foo` objects, but not other `ArrayList`s.
2. The `prepArrayLists` adds the contents of 20 empty `ArrayList`s to `fooList`.  They're all empty, so nothing is added.
3. You are attempting to get the first `Foo` out of `fooList`, and there isn't one.  This fails with a compiler error, because you can't assign a `Foo` to an `ArrayList<Foo>`.

To have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s of `Foo`, you need `fooList` to be an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>>`, not an `ArrayList<Foo>`.  You'll need to change the `addAll` line in `prepArrayLists` to `add`, so you can add each `ArrayList` to `fooList`.  That will allow you to compile your code to get the first `ArrayList` and add a new `Foo` to it.

You may want to have `fooList` declared as follows, to follow the "code to the interface" guidelines.

```
private static List<List<Foo>> fooList = new ArrayList<List<Foo>>();
```

You can still add `ArrayList`s in `prepArrayLists`, but `temp` will need to be declared as `List<Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `fooList` as an `ArrayList<Foo>`, that is, a list of `Foo` objects. You didn't post the compiler error message, but it's probably (correctly) telling you that a `Foo` cannot be converted to an `ArrayList<Foo>`.

If you want it to be a list of lists, you should declare it as an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Foo>>`, or possibly `ArrayList<List<Foo>>`, or maybe even `ArrayList<Collection<Foo>>`.

Comment: That helped! Thank you :) How can I access it though? Using the ArrayList.get() method as usual?